# If $f\in A_k(V)$ then $\operatorname{Alt}f=(k!)f$, is the converse true?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $f\in L_k(V)$ (the set of all $k$-linear maps on $V$) then we define the alternating operator $\operatorname{Alt}:L_k(V)\to A_k(V)$ using the following way,
$$
\operatorname{Alt}(f)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\operatorname{sgn}\sigma(\sigma f)
$$
Now it's clear that if $f\in A_k(V)$ then $\operatorname{Alt}f=(k!)f$, but this question came up to my mind: is the converse necessarily true? I'm inclined to say yes but I don't know how to prove it: it's clear that the RHS is a $k!$ sum of exactly the same element but that doesn't necessarily mean that the terms of the sum must also be the same. I'd appreciate it deeply if someone can help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse is true. It must be the case that $\operatorname{Alt} f \in A_k(V)$. So, we have
$$
\operatorname{Alt} f = k! f \implies f = \frac 1{k!} \operatorname{Alt} f \implies f \in A_k(V)
$$

Comment: +1, note to OP that if the question pertains to a vector space over a field of characteristic less than $p$ (which seems unlikely) then I think the converse is false (but not sure).

Comment: @hunter I'm interested, what would happen in that case?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for your answer! It was very clear actually! What about when we're dealing with a field of characteristic less than $p$ as hunter suggested?

Comment: Presumably, the condition should be that the field has non-zero characteristic less than $k$ instead of "less than $p$". In that case, we have $k! = 0$ so that the equation we're concerned with is really
$$
\operatorname{Alt}(f) = 0.
$$
The "converse" that we're interested in is whether $\operatorname{Alt}(f) = 0$ implies that $f \in A_k(V)$. I'm not sure what the answer is; if you're really interested I recommend posting a new question about this.